# How to use CCActionProperty, Does it not exist in Cocos2d 3.0?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I was looking up the different abilities of Cocos2d, and don't quite understand what property is being modified here:

```
id rot = [CCPropertyAction actionWithDuration:2 key:@"rotation" from:0 to:-270];
id rot_back = [rot reverse];
id rot_seq = [CCSequence actions:rot, rot_back, nil];
```

Specifically, the "rotation" of what sprite? Rotation is a property of CCSprite, but I see no CCSprite here, so I'm very confused.

Furthermore, it seems to have existed in an earlier version of Cocos2d, so what has happened to it?

Comment: As @Skullz mentioned in his answer, you assign the actions you have defined to your sprite using your sprites' runAction method.

Comment: instead of property actions use CCActionCallBlock

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for CCActionTween? https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v3/cocos2d/CCActionTween.h

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen `CCPropertyAction` used... I'll show you how I would do what you exampled.

```
// Create rotate action
CCActionRotateBy *rotateAction = [CCActionRotateBy actionWithDuration:2.0f angle:-270];

// Create a copy of that action and reverse it
id reverseAction = [[rotateAction copy] reverse];

// Create a sequence of actions in order
CCActionSequence *sequenceAction = [CCActionSequence actions:rotateAction,reverseAction, nil];

// mySprite will run actions in order
[mySprite runAction:sequenceAction];
```

In previous versions of cocos2d the actions were `CCRotateBy` and `CCSequence`, they just changed names for the sake of confusion.

All cocos2d actions will have `CCAction...` before them to classify them as actions.